# When and how to patent a business model?

Tags: concepts

I have an idea for a business model that's never really been done before. There exists current businesses that accomplish the same goal, but not in the way I envision it. For example, think about Uber and taxi services. They both accomplish the same goal (deliver the passenger), but accomplish it in different models.

Actually, Uber would be a good example of the type of patents I need. I did some research on them and they've patented a whole bunch of ideas, such as "PROVIDING ON-DEMAND SERVICES THROUGH USE OF PORTABLE COMPUTING DEVICES" and "PROVIDING USER FEEDBACK FOR TRANSPORT SERVICES THROUGH USE OF MOBILE DEVICES" and "PROVIDING ON-DEMAND SERVICES THROUGH USE OF PORTABLE COMPUTING DEVICES" This is exactly the type of patent I'm looking for. They're not really a patent for an invention, but more like for a concept. I thought these abstract ideas couldn't be patented?

The second question is when to file? I plan to build the platform then launch it, and then patent it when it becomes successful, but I'm afraid when it's gaining traction someone will copy the idea. I don't have the funds to patent it right now before launch, so I'm not sure what to do.

Lastly, Uber has filed dozens of patents for different features and ideas. Is it possible to file all things in a single patent to cut back on costs?

1. What type of patents does Uber use?
2. Is there any way to protect my idea during the initial launch without spending a lot, and then patenting it when it becomes successful?
3. Can I file multiple ideas and concepts into a single patent, or do I need separate patents for each entity?

Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: FYI india doesnot allow the business method patents

Comment: During this phase, I'm focusing on the US, but I do plan to expand to other countries if it's successful. Thanks.

Comment: The best way is to define it in terms of Algorithms and specific programs running on computers. Note that converting Human interaction to be displaced by computers is not patentable.

Comment: defining it in terms of Algorithms and specific programs running on computers could be rejected as abstract idea

Comment: A Business model includes revenues strams, cost structure, etc, etc. Difficult to patent in my opinion.